# How to get the focused control in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How to get the focused control in Windows 8?
Now I am using `OnLostFocus` and `OnGoFocus`, using a variable to flag when the control has the focus. It works fine for a small number of controls, but I would need a general solution.

In Windows Forms, there is a function to get the focused control but I cannot find it in Windows 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use FocusManager to get the currently focused control.